# Super User Question of the Week #30

Tags: discussion, status-completed, superuser-blog, question-of-the-week

Now we're into week 30 of the "Top Question" of Super User in the [Super User blog](http://blog.superuser.com). Please post and vote for your favorite question for this week.

Please post any question that you feel is of worth and the reason why.  Try not to promote your own questions or answers for publicity's sake.  We are looking for questions that are of similar par to those selected in the [Super User Contest](https://meta.superuser.com/search?q=super+user+contest). If you like a posted question then vote it up. Each week we'll to try to post about a question and its contents.

When submitting a QotW, please indicate if you would be interested in writing about it for the blog. This is a factor which we take into consideration when selecting what to blog about - we need a post we can actually say something interesting about; it shouldn't be something we've written about too much before, and it helps to have somebody interested in writing the article.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**[How to find and remove "spicy" media files from my PC](https://superuser.com/questions/331857/how-to-find-and-remove-spicy-media-files-from-my-pc)**

I think that this is worthy of question of the week:

- It is probably a question a lot of people have.
- It has sparked a lot of interesting conversation about cleaning out files from hard drives (especially if you don't know what they're called and you can't just format the whole thing).
- I think it could be something interesting to blog about.

As far as writing the blog post - I wish I could, but I'm really too busy at the moment to do that.

Comment: And how can we not promote a guy who is trying to change his ways for someone he loves? Where stubbornness and martial infidelity is the rage among society, we should applaud such humbling efforts.

Comment: [410 Gone](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/5296/super-user-question-of-the-week-30-was-just-deleted?lq=1)