# Super User question of the week #30 was just deleted?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, specific-question, deleted-questions, question-of-the-week

I wonder why [Super User Question of the Week #30](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/3408/super-user-question-of-the-week-30) (not sure if it made to the blog), being [How to find and remove "spicy" media files from my PC](https://superuser.com/questions/331857/how-to-find-and-remove-spicy-media-files-from-my-pc), was just deleted?

I think it was quite a nice question: much more "Super" than [What are the Windows A: and B: drives used for?](https://superuser.com/questions/231273/what-are-the-windows-a-and-b-drives-used-for) just to name one. Fine, some answers were about the social aspect, but why delete the whole thing?

I'd vote to undelete but I can't, given a moderator deleted it.

Answer (score 5):

Due to it having been a QOTW, I've undeleted it and locked the post for historical significance. It's not really a particularly on-topic question, but I think in this edge case it should be kept, for that reason.

Comment: I cannot actually find it on the blog. So, if you agree with the deletion, then it's apparently 2 moderators who think so...

Comment: @Arjan I don't believe it was actually written up, but if it was chosen, we should still keep it around. I do think that having it locked makes sense though.

Comment: I don't even see why it should be closed, let alone locked, but we don't have to agree on everything.

Comment: Typically, a good question for SU will not have 30+ answers. This a clear sign that it is **not constructive** or too open-ended.

Comment: Did you read the question, @iglvzx? Sure, some (many) answers were not Super User material; I would not object to deleting those.